# How do I remove non-unique values from a csv database field

Tags: mysql, magento2

I have a Magento 2 MySQL database where one of the attributes is a varchar that contains a CSV list of IDs. Some of these fields were added to, so the list is just a string of duplicate values.

| value_id | attribute_id | store_id | entity_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27808 | 145 | 0 | 1232 | 16,15 |
| 29821 | 145 | 0 | 1327 | 16,15,13,29,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49 |
| 29804 | 145 | 0 | 1326 | 16,15,13,29,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49 |
| 25779 | 145 | 0 | 1126 | 16,15,13,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49 |
| 27733 | 145 | 0 | 1228 | 16,15,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15, |
| 27755 | 145 | 0 | 1229 | 16,15,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15, |
| 27791 | 145 | 0 | 1231 | 16,15,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15,16,15, |

Is there a way to reduce these duplicate values down to just the unique values for each row?

Comment: Use `explode()` to convert the string to an array, `array_unique()` to remove duplicates, then `implode()` to convert the array back to a comma-separated string.

Comment: To do it in MySQL, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows for how to split a comma-separated value into multiple rows. Then use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)` to convert it back to CSV with duplicates removed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Provide: precise MySQL version; complete CREATE TABLE script.